# Get rows with highest COUNT() in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have been having a really hard time figuring this out. I cannot understand if I'm doing something wrong or there is no possible way to achieve this.

I have a table `movies_characters` and it has 2 columns `movie_id` and `character_id`.

This table has the information of which character appeared in which movie.

With the following query I've got results that has 3 characters that are appeared in most movies.

```
select character_id, count(*) appearances from movies_characters group by character_id order by appearances desc;
```

You can check my working query here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3n1GYbzSwyaEGEpbjBdE2a/0

As you can see I got 3 characters with id `2, 3, 10` that are appeared 6 times.

I want my query to show only those 3 characters not all of them. I don't know how to do it.

Comment: There are actually better ways of doing this than the answers in the duplicate link... A CTE would be much cleaner. Make your query a CTE and then `SELECT * FROM cte WHERE appearances = (SELECT MAX(appearances) FROM cte)`

Comment: There is no column name appearances in my table.

Comment: There is a column named appearances in the result set of the query in your question. Here is some documentation on CTEs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html